# Vue2: Invalid regular expression flag

Tags: javascript, regex, vuejs2

I have a Vue view that loads some html and extracts the body-tag content from it.
Vue return the following error:

> ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/views/Inbox.vue
>   Module parse failed: Invalid regular expression flag (170:43) You may
>   need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

My regex looks ok: I tested it here:

https://regex101.com/r/noPGfP/1

This is my (simplified) code:

```
export default {
    name: "inbox",
    methods: {
        load(rs) {
            _Api._get('load', {id: rs["uuid"]}).then((response) => {
                if(response.status==200 && response.statusText=="OK") {
                    var html = response.body;
                    var body = html.match(/\<body[^\>]*\>(.*)\<\/body\>/si);
                }
            });
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: `/s` is a very new flag - better not to use it yet. Also, better to use something like `DOMParser` rather than a regular expression.

Comment: `s` is an ECMAScript 2018 extension. Not all browsers or tools support it. Remove `s` and replace all dots in regex with `[\s\S]`.

Comment: Guys these should be answers

Comment: It looks like there are transpilers for it, but you'll have to implement them, see bottom of https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-dotall-flag

Comment: Please see the marked questions for more details. If they didn't answer your question please edit accordingly.

Comment: Thank you guys - I blindly trusted the regex tool